# simulating packet dropping in a wireless network 1

Tags: routes, tcl, simulator

When I run `tclsh aodv1.tcl`, I get an error from this tcl command:

```
set ns_ [new Simulator]
```

The error message is:

```
invalid command name "new"
    while executing
"new Simulator"
    invoked from within
"set ns_ [new Simulator]"
    (file "aodv1.tcl" line 3)
child process exited abnormally
```

How can I rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

That's a reasonably clear error message; it says that the command `new` is not understood. It's not a standard part of Tcl, so that's relatively expected. What the code *probably* needs is a `package require` of the library package that provides the functionality (which belongs at the top of the script, just below the `#!` line if you're using one).

Which package might that be? Well, the main candidates are [incr Tcl] and OTcl; in general Tcl code, [incr Tcl] would be the most likely, but in this case — because of the word `Simulator` as the name of the class to instantiate — I'm guessing that it's actually OTcl code, and probably NS2 code at that. That means that you're looking at ***either***

```
package require OTcl
```

***or*** running with the `ns` program as outlined in NS2 tutorials (as that automatically requires the relevant package for you).

Comment: Just requiring OTcl isn't very likely to do you any good. Still, looking for a package to require _is_ a good first thing to try if the interpreter can't understand your code.